# How to Generate an Angular 2 application by reversing our own ORACLE database schema using celerio

Tags: java, angularjs, oracle, maven

i watched here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBrgeykyTGs&t=29s a video that shows how to Generate an Angular 2 application from an a database schema... in less than 3 minutes.
 the github link to  the project is https://github.com/jaxio/celerio-angular-quickstart/tree/master/quickstart
  i followed the steps shown in the above link n everything worked fine. then i tried to Generate an Angular 2 application from my ORAClE database which i have already created .i did some configurations but it didn't work.i am wondering how to  configure pom.xml and celerio-maven-plugin.xml properly.

Comment: link to my pom.xml file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8vFTkSqY3bCTmotaFM0eFR4Mi1KYTRlV0stQXZ1cGNuOGw0                 link to my celerio-maven-plugin.xml file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8vFTkSqY3bCU1hJQnRnVnFMamhxak90a2ItcTdtZVgtWmMw

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)